# message.author.dmChannel.awaitMessages not working

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have a setup command where the setup takes place in DMs. Sending the first message works but whenever I dm the bot it doesn’t detect my messages.
Code:

```js
const filter = m => m.content;
message.author.dmChannel.awaitMessages(filter, {
  max: 1,
  time: 60000,
  errors: ["time"]
}).then(collected => {
  collected.reply("message collected message");
}.catch(() => message.author.send("ran out of time message")
```

When the time runs out it dms me the ran out of time message

I also tried this but it also didn’t work

```js
const filter = m => m.content;
message.author.dmChannel.awaitMessages({
  filter,
  max: 1,
  time: 60000,
  errors: ["time"]
}).then(collected => {
  collected.reply("message collected message");
}.catch(() => message.author.send("ran out of time message")
```

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: I use discord.js v13 and Node 16.1.0

Answer (score 1):

[`TextChannel.awaitMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages) now only takes 1 argument. This includes the filter property in the object. Changing it to this will work:

```js
const filter = m => m.content;
message.author.dmChannel.awaitMessages({
  filter,
  max: 1,
  time: 60000,
  errors: ["time"]
})
```

Comment: I already tried that, it doesn’t work